# create hyperlink from text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to create a hyperlink from an existing url that I would like to 'share' with others. What I mean to say is that I am creating a 'share page' option for my phone app and I pass the current url via querystring to my SharePage.xaml, whereby the user may select an option to share the current url that the webbrowser control is on. For instance, in my SharePage.xaml.cs my code is as follows:

SharePage.xaml.cs

```
    string urlToShare;

    public SharePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("curUrl", out urlToShare);
    }

    private void SocialNetworks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

        Uri shareUrl = new Uri(urlToShare);            

        shareLinkTask.Title = "Shared Link!";
        shareLinkTask.LinkUri = shareUrl;
        shareLinkTask.Message = "Check out this link!";

        shareLinkTask.Show();
    }
```

As of now this works although the LinkUri part of the message shows up as plain text instead of a hyperlink (which is what I would like to give as an option). The purpose would be to simply facilitate more efficient, quicker navigation to a url so that the user does not have to copy and paste the url into a web browser manually (something I've found annoying on the Windows Phone). Is there any way to do this in code behind in my SocialNetworks_Click event? Any code help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I have never messed with the Hyperlink option in C# as I am new to the language (and cannot find anything online about doing this in code behind if thats possible). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a lame question, but have you tried calling the UpdateLayout() method on the page?

Comment: @Eugene I have not because as my code is currently everything is working correctly and is rendered fine on the respective pages. I was wondering how I could create a hyperlink from the querystring url loaded in the OnNavigatedTo event and then use that hyperlink to send in a message.

Comment: I had an issue when a layout element was not getting updated, and someone suggested using the UpdateLayout() method on the element, it solved my problem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439518/using-visualtreehelper-on-listbox-cant-get-listboxitems the accepted answer. I thought it could be worth a try :)

Comment: Where is the uri not being made a hyperlink?

Comment: @Matt Lacey, 'shareLinkTask.LinkUri = shareUrl;' as far as I can tell a hyperlink is not supposed to be made (to compare, when selecting the default IE browser for Windows Phone 'share page' option only plain text in url format shows as well), so I thought it might be cool to create that plain text that is already in a url format into a hyperlink for users' convenience. For instance say I am sharing http://www. bing.com, LinkUri shows the url but it is only plain text and not a hyperlink. I've messed around with making a hyperlink but LinkUri only accepts type Uri. Is there a work around?

Comment: The shared link above for bing.com (and for any other arbitrary website) is the absoluteuri version but I could not type that in properly above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused about what the ShareLinkTask is supposed to do.

This isn't meant to  be displayed as a link in your app, or even in the task UI.

On the "Post a link" page this will be just text (and not tappable).
When the link appears in Twitter or Facebook or LinkedIn or whatever else you're sharing to then it will be a valid link that can be tapped/clicked.

Comment: ok thanks for clearing that up, I realized that it was only supposed to show up as plain text before sharing but I did not realize it was going to be tappable afterwards.