# Hide the template elements in code-behind file

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListHeaderTemplate that consists of a list and a button. You will see how are they distributed in the code below. My problem is that I need sometimes hide button in code-behind file. How I can do that?!
XAML:

```
 <toolkit:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" ListHeader="{Binding EpsLaterItems}" IsFlatList="True" ItemsSource="{Binding EpsItems}" x:Name="EPS" SelectionChanged="EPS_SelectionChanged_1">
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource BmpConverter}}" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,18,0"/>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="300">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, ConverterCulture=ru-RU, StringFormat=f}" 
                                       FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFD65B2D" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Foreground="Aqua" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource BmpConverter}}" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,18,0"/>
                                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="300">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, ConverterCulture=ru-RU, StringFormat=f}" 
                                       FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFD65B2D" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Foreground="Aqua" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                                <Button x:Name="footerEpsLater" Content="more..." 
                    FontSize="30" Foreground="SteelBlue" Style="{StaticResource StyleForButton}" BorderBrush="#FFFF2121"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="more..." FontSize="30" Foreground="SteelBlue" Click="footerEPS_Click_1" Style="{StaticResource StyleForButton}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
                </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

If i do like this `footerEpsLater.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;` I get the error: footerEpsLater does not exist in this context

Comment: Try using VisualTreeHelper to drill into the items of your listbox.

Comment: @Eugene, Can you show me an example of the use based on my example?

Comment: Sure. MSDN overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx and here is how I tried using it (look at the question code): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439518/using-visualtreehelper-on-listbox-cant-get-listboxitems